# SFMC Mobile Connect & Emoticon / Emoji

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

Does anyone know a way (or could it be a feature) to send Emoji or Emoticon's in an SMS (MMS) from Salesforce Marketing Cloud (Mobile Connect).

I'm aware it can be done from Mobile Push - I understand there are limitations/restrictions around SMS - so I'm very interested to know if anyone has a hack/solution.

For example - I want to send an emoji of a Christmas Tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was just asked in MC Success Community as well and the response from SF side was that *Emojis are non-GSM characters, and only some country/code combos support the use of non-GSM characters*.

So depending on the country/code you're trying to send to, try using the code on some test number and see if that works. If not, there's no alternative at the moment.